# insert Time in to database using Codeiniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form which is for company registration,Which has fields for open hours and close hours for each day in a week.

I have Two Tables Store the time

```
Timing | Week
```

In my timing Table i have four columns

```
id  | company_id | day | open |close
```

week Table contain each day id

```
id | name
```

Suppose on Monday the company which is open on 8 am and closed on 3 pm .
Like Monday user fill all the days like whenever is open and close, 
Now how can i insert these data in by its day by day into timing Table.

```
   id c_id day  open         close  
    1   1   1   06:28:13    14:47:32    
    2   1   2   06:28:13    14:47:32    
    3   1   3   06:28:13    16:47:32    
    4   1   4   06:28:13    14:00:32    
    5   1   5   06:28:13    12:07:32    
    6   1   6   06:28:13    18:47:32    
    7   1   7   06:28:13    19:47:32
```

I want to store some thing like this here day column refers to the week table which has id of the name of day.

I do not understand how to insert. i have also tried to insert_batch.

**This is my form**
[image: My form is like this]

**Controller:**

i have tried many times but i could not find way to do this.

I know this is not the right way, but How can i do this???

```
    $time['open']['monday_open']    = $this->input->post('monday');
    $time['close']['monday_close']  = $this->input->post('monday_close');
```